# How to add WhatsApp share button to PHP website?

Tags: php, share, whatsapp

Below links are using Facebook and other networks to share post

How to place and link a Whatsapp share button?

```
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook" onclick="OpenShareWindow('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ENCODED_URL}}')"></a>
               <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter" onclick="OpenShareWindow('https://twitter.com/home?status={{ENCODED_URL}}')"></a>
               <a href="#" class="fa fa-google" onclick="OpenShareWindow('https://plus.google.com/share?url={{ENCODED_URL}}')"></a>
               <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin" onclick="OpenShareWindow('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={{ENCODED_URL}}&title={{TITLE}}')"></a>
               <a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest" onclick="OpenShareWindow('https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={{ENCODED_URL}}&media={{THUMBNAIL}}')"></a>
               <a href="#" class="fa fa-tumblr" onclick="OpenShareWindow('http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url={{ENCODED_URL}}')"></a>
               <a href="#" class="fa fa-reddit" onclick="OpenShareWindow('http://www.reddit.com/submit?url={{ENCODED_URL}}')"></a>
```

Comment: What problem specifically are you having with your objective?

Answer (score 3):

To create your own link, use https://wa.me/ where the  is a full phone number in international format. Omit any zeroes, brackets or dashes when adding the phone number in international format. For a detailed explanation on international numbers, read this article. Please keep in mind that this phone number must have an active account on WhatsApp.

Use: https://wa.me/15551234567

Don't use: https://wa.me/+001-(555)1234567

To create your own link with a pre-filled message that will automatically appear in the text field of a chat, use https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber/?text=urlencodedtext where whatsappphonenumber is a full phone number in international format and URL-encodedtext is the URL-encoded pre-filled message.

Example:https://wa.me/15551234567?text=I'm%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale

To create a link with just a pre-filled message, use https://wa.me/?text=urlencodedtext

Example:https://wa.me/?text=I'm%20inquiring%20about%20the%20apartment%20listing

After clicking on the link, you will be shown a list of contacts you can send your message to.

Answer (score 0):

What is about using a URL Scheme?

from the WhatsApp Docu :
https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012

**Custom URL Scheme**

WhatsApp provides a custom URL scheme to interact with WhatsApp:

If you have a website and want to open a WhatsApp chat with a pre-filled message, you can use our custom URL scheme to do so. Opening whatsapp://send?text= followed by the text to send, will open WhatsApp, allow the user to choose a contact, and pre-fill the input field with the specified text.

feel free to add also other messengers  ..

**Threema:**

threema://compose?text=Hello

see docu:
https://threema.ch/de/faq/url_actions

**Telegram:**

tg://msg?text=  or

tg://share?url=www.example.com?t=12&text=Check%20out%20this%20url

Answer (score 0):

First: [**Official Whatsapp Sharing Documentation**](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/).  Take a look at what happens when you use WhatsApp, but don't indicate a phone number: http://wa.me/?text=mytest.  I get the result:

> We couldn't find the page you were looking for

Hopefully this is not what you intended to share!  I highly recommend using one of the following formats, without the `wa.me` domain, but with the `api.whatsapp.com` domain:

> https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere
>
> https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere&phone=123

If you are interested in watching a project that keeps track of these URLs, then check us out!: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#whatsapp

[image: Social Share URLs]